# Mobile Navbar is not auto collapsing after clicking link

Tags: javascript, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

Using Bootstrap 3 mobile 'hamburger' navbar opens on click but does not automatically collapse after link is clicked

I have tried various setting and unsetting of navbar-collapse inside class divs

```
<div class="overlay">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top mynavbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbar-mobile" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'welcome' %}">Fred</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-mobile">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-list navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#page-top" class="section-link" data-target="page-top">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="section-link" data-target="about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services" class="section-link" data-target="services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="section-link" data-target="portfolio">Employment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blogs" class="section-link" data-target="testimonials">Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="section-link" data-target="contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="welcome-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Fred</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span class="typed"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="welcome-scroll">
                        <div class="arrow bounce">
                            <a href="#about" class="section-link" data-target="about"><i
                                    class="fa fa-long-arrow-down fa-2x"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```